# How to open and save array in MongoDB with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb

I have a problem with my aggregation framework inside a MongoDB. This problem is caused that I save data in MongoDB in Array.

I want that, when the data is saved it's not in the array. Explanation on screenshots below.

Here is how I save data inside a MongoDB. This part is the main problem -  `const myobj = { Name: symbol, Array: BTCdata[0], Date: dateTime };` As you can see I'm having an `Array: BTCdata[0]` it was my first opening of the array, since before I was having array inside an array. (Check on of the screenshots). On one of the screenshots, you can see 2 arrays. Array > Array > 0 > Object. It was when I was having `Array:BTCdata` when I changed to `Array:BTCdata[0]` on of the arrays disappear.

How can I open another array that data will be like on a second screenshot? I just don't need these arrays cause I can't use aggregation correctly.

[image: First]

[image]

**Problematic Code Area**

```
let db = await MongoClient.connect(url, { useUnifiedTopology: true });
    const dbo = db.db('Crypto');
    const myobj = { Name: symbol, Array: BTCdata[0], Date: dateTime };
    await dbo.collection(symbol).insertOne(myobj);
    console.log('1 document inserted');
    db.close();
```

**Code Part on receiving data from API**

```
  const btcusdtdata = data.map(d => {
        return {
            Open: parseFloat(d[1]),
            High: parseFloat(d[2]),
            Low: parseFloat(d[3]),
            Close: parseFloat(d[4]),
            Volume: parseFloat(d[5]),
            Timespan: 30,
        }
    });
```

If needed I can add full code to show the full logic.

**EDIT1**
I tried the way as @Molda suggested

```
    const myobj = { Name: symbol, Array: BTCdata[0][0], Date: dateTime };
```

I receive in MongoDB that array is null. Without any data in it.

**EDIT2**
As @prasad_ requested here is JSON view. I hope I did it correctly. This is what I receive after calling the API(result from my terminal)

```
[
  {
    Open: 0.0000135,
    High: 0.00001355,
    Low: 0.00001337,
    Close: 0.0000134,
    Volume: 7584645,
    Timespan: 30
  }
]
```

Comment: To get the inner object use another `[0]` like so `BTCdata[0][0]` then you can extend the object with _id and Name using `var data = Object.assign({ _id: .., Name: ..}, BTCdata[0][0]);`

Comment: @Molda Thanks for answer! I tried your way and it doesn't work. I receive "null" instead of data. Is there possibilities that you show on my example? Maybe I declare it wrongly. I will edit main question with your try

Comment: Please post sample document as a JSON (as text and formatted properly).

Comment: @prasad_ thanks for answer! I edited main question, I hope I understand your request correctly. Check the EDIT2 please.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

```
const myobj = Object.assign({ Name: symbol, Date: dateTime }, BTCdata[0]);
```

Thanks to this wonderful function - `Object.assign`. Doesn't need to have another `[0]` in the code. Just need to setup `Object.assign` and correctly put the array.